# Usuario "dummy" para entrar en local no me funciona

Tags: spring-boot, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Estoy tratando de abordar un problema relacionado con la incompatibilidad de bibliotecas en mi aplicación en un entorno local. He decidido implementar un control de usuario "dummy" en lugar del estándar debido a la complejidad y el costo asociado con la implementación del estándar. Ahora, necesitas crear y probar una propiedad para gestionar el uso de este control de usuario en local.

Paso 1: Agregué la propiedad de configuración al archivo de propiedades:

```
user.control.dummy.enabled=true
```

Paso 2: Modifiqué la clase BaseController inyectando la implementación de UserControlService de acuerdo con la propiedad de configuración:

public class BaseController extends AbstractWebMvcController {

```
private static final String PARAM_CURRENT_PAGE = "currentPage";
private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(BaseController.class);

private static final String PAGINATION = "pagination";
private static final String USER_DHF = "userDef";

@Autowired
private MessageSource msg;
@Autowired
private CtuCtrluserService ctuCtrluserService;

@Value("${user.control.dummy.enabled}") // Lee la propiedad de configuracionn
private boolean useDummyControlUser; // Indica si se utiliza el control de usuario dummy
private DummyUserControlServiceImpl dummyUserControlService;



@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected <T> T getSessionAttr(HttpServletRequest request, String attr) {
    return (T) request.getSession().getAttribute(attr);
}

protected <T extends Serializable> void setSessionAttr(HttpServletRequest request, String attrName, T obj) {
    request.getSession().setAttribute(attrName, obj);
}

protected boolean setUserInSession(HttpServletRequest request) {
    ImiUserDetails userDetails = SecurityUtils.getLoggedUserDetails();
    CtuUsuariVO ctrlUserUser;
    try {
        // se utiliza el servicio de control de usuario correspondiente
        if (useDummyControlUser) {
            // obtener el usuario en el control de usuario dummy
            ctrlUserUser = dummyUserControlService.getUserDetails(userDetails.getUsername());
        } else {
            ctrlUserUser = ctuCtrluserService.dadesObtenir(userDetails.getUsername());
        }

        String USER_DEF = null;
        setSessionAttr(request, USER_DEF, ctrlUserUser);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Couldn't set user in session", e);
        return false;
    }
}

protected String getSetUserInSession(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String user = "";
    String USER_DEF = null;
    CtuUsuariVO ctrlUserUser = (CtuUsuariVO) getSessionAttr(request, USER_DEF);
    if (ctrlUserUser != null && ctrlUserUser.getCodi() != null) {
        user = ctrlUserUser.getCodi();
    } else {
        user = request.getUserPrincipal().getName();
        ctrlUserUser = new CtuUsuariVO();
        ctrlUserUser.setCodi(user);
        setSessionAttr(request, USER_DEF, ctrlUserUser);
    }
    return user;
}

protected String getMessage(String key, Object... params) {
    return msg.getMessage(key, params, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
}

protected Pagination resetPagination(HttpServletRequest request, long totalItems) {
    return setPagination(request, new Pagination(totalItems));
}

protected Pagination getPagination(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return (Pagination) getSessionAttr(request, getPaginationAttrName(request));
}

protected Pagination setPagination(HttpServletRequest request, long totalItems) {
    int currentPage = 0;
    String currentPageStr = request.getParameter(PARAM_CURRENT_PAGE);
    try {
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(currentPageStr))
            currentPage = Integer.parseInt(currentPageStr) - 1;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e);
    }
    Pagination pagination = getPagination(request);
    if (pagination == null) {
        pagination = resetPagination(request, totalItems);
    }
    pagination.setTotalItems(totalItems);
    pagination.setCurrentPage(currentPage);
    return setPagination(request, pagination);
}

private Pagination setPagination(HttpServletRequest request, Pagination pagination) {
    setSessionAttr(request, getPaginationAttrName(request), pagination);
    request.setAttribute("page", pagination);
    return pagination;
}

private String getPaginationAttrName(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return PAGINATION + request.getRequestURI();
}
```

}'

Paso 3/0: Creé la implementación DummyUserControlServiceImpl:

@Service
public class DummyUserControlServiceImpl.java implements UserControlService {

```
@Override
public CtuUsuariVO getUserDetails(String username) {
    
    CtuUsuariVO user = new CtuUsuariVO();
    user.setUsername(username);
    user.setNombre("Usuario Dummy");
    user.setDetails("Información adicional del usuario dummy");
    return user;
}
```

}

Paso 3/1 creé una clase que implemente UserControlService para el control de usuario dummy:

@Service
public class DummyUserControlServiceImpl.java implements UserControlService {

```
@Override
public CtuUsuariVO getUserDetails(String username) {
    
    CtuUsuariVO user = new CtuUsuariVO();
    user.setUsername(username);
    user.setNombre("Usuario Dummy");
    user.setDetails("Información adicional del usuario dummy");
    return user;
}
```

}

Con esto no me funciona con el usuario "dummy"
Alguna ayuda?